# How to use property in View.OnClickListener(kotlin, android)

Tags: android, kotlin

Please understand using a translator.
Below is the code I wrote.

```
val lister = object : View.OnClickListener{
    val textView1:TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView1)
    val toggleButton1:ToggleButton = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1)
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        if(toggleButton1.isChecked == true) {
            textView1.text = "ON"
        }else{
            textView1.text = "OFF"
        }
    }
}
```

But this code didn't work. error name is E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
So I modified it like the following code.

```
val lister1 = object : View.OnClickListener{
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val toggleButton1:ToggleButton = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1)
        val textView1:TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView1)
        if(toggleButton1.isChecked == true) {
            textView1.text = "ON"
        }else{
            textView1.text = "OFF"
        }
    }
}
```

It worked well when I moved toggleButton1 and textView1 property to the onclick function.
But I wonder why it doesn't work when I write it like the first code. I'd appreciate it if you let me know.
Below is the whole error.

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: kr.co.yeaeun.viewbasic, PID: 11834
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{kr.co.yeaeun.viewbasic/kr.co.yeaeun.viewbasic.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:173)
at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:744)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:839)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:630)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:223)
at kr.co.yeaeun.viewbasic.MainActivity$lister1$1.(MainActivity.kt:55)
at kr.co.yeaeun.viewbasic.MainActivity.(MainActivity.kt:54)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

> > full code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val textView1:TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView1)
    //val textView2:TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView2)

    val toggleButton1:ToggleButton = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1)
    val toggleButton2:ToggleButton = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2)

    val button1:Button = findViewById(R.id.button1)
    val button2:Button = findViewById(R.id.button2)
    val button3:Button = findViewById(R.id.button3)
    val button4:Button = findViewById(R.id.button4)

    button1.setOnClickListener{
        if(toggleButton1.isChecked == true){
            textView1.text = "ON"
        } else{
            textView1.text = "OFF"
        }
    }
    button2.setOnClickListener{
        toggleButton1.isChecked = true
    }
    button3.setOnClickListener{
        toggleButton1.isChecked = false
    }
    button4.setOnClickListener {
        toggleButton1.toggle()
    }

    toggleButton1.setOnClickListener(lister1)
    toggleButton2.setOnClickListener {
        val textView2:TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView2)
        if(toggleButton1.isChecked == true) {
            textView2.text = "ON"
        }else{
            textView2.text = "OFF"
        }
    }
  }
val lister1 = object : View.OnClickListener{
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val toggleButton1:ToggleButton = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1)
        val textView1:TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView1)
        if(toggleButton1.isChecked == true) {
            textView1.text = "ON"
        }else{
            textView1.text = "OFF"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "But this code didn't work" ← Please write specific, throw an Exception or onClick was not called?

Comment: Ok, modified it.

Comment: first code does not work because onClick event does not know anything about textView1 and toggleButton1

Comment: Good, But more error logs are FATAL EXCEPTION below. Need to that to know why throws an exception. It's the key point

Comment: Why doesn't onClick event know? I defined textView1 and toggleButton1 within the same object that inherited View.OnClickListener.

Comment: Okay. I wrote the whole error.

Comment: Check MainActivity.kt:55, Maybe textView1 is null. As I expected, when you initialize lister, MainActivity layout has not textView1 and toggleButton1

Comment: When I call the listener, do I reset the listener unconditionally?

Comment: Ok, show code where you apply a listener to view. What is object?

Comment: val lister1 = object : View.OnClickListener < I think the object was created here.

Comment: "When I call the listener, do I reset the listener unconditionally?" ← No

When,

Init listener → not inflated textview and toggle button,
onClick → Inflated textview and toggle button

---

Did you write that code before setContentView()?

Comment: I see where it is created. Show where you are applying it to a view. show full code where you do this. Probabaly onCreate method, just show full code.

Comment: No, I wrote the code after setContentView().

Comment: Ok, I add full code

Comment: look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, when I see full code it is easy to say where is the problem. See this Java code example, which will throw RuntimeException:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btnTakePhoto = findViewById(R.id.take_photo);
        btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }


    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        Button btnTakePhoto = findViewById(R.id.take_photo);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btnTakePhoto.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "dszfa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

So I defined listener here as an Activity field. And what is going on then? This field is initialized before the method onCreate() is called. So there is no place to find View by id, because you did not set content view before! it's different if you put the code  `Button btnTakePhoto = findViewById(R.id.take_photo);` inside onClick method. There is no possibility someone can push button before view was created.

Comment: Thank you so much, then I have question. Is the call to the OnCreate method initializing all properties in Activity?

Comment: It depends only on you. if you initialize properties as local field there is no nessesary to initialize them inside onCreate. But regarding view elements you suppose to use findViewById() method only after setContentView() inside onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

View.CustomListener is not a View. It is a Listener class.
You need use smth like next, but it is a bad way. Listener should not save ui views as properties

```
class CustomView : View {
...
    inner class CustomListener : View.OnClickListener{
        val toggleButton1:ToggleButton = this@CustomView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1)
        val textView1:TextView = this@CustomView.findViewById(R.id.textView1)
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            if(toggleButton1.isChecked == true) {
                textView1.text = "ON"
            }else{
                textView1.text = "OFF"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If toggleButton1 and textView are children of listened view then you can use

```
val lister1 = object : View.OnClickListener{
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val toggleButton1:ToggleButton? = view?.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1)
        val textView1:TextView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.textView1)
        if(toggleButton1?.isChecked == true) {
            textView1?.text = "ON"
        }else{
            textView1?.text = "OFF"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's an error with the second code "view?.findViewById(...)". I'll keep that in mind. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Fixed view types to nullable

Comment: Could you provide parent view layout and error?

Answer (score 0):

Working sample

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.view_main)
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        (button as View).setOnClickListener(listener)
    }

    val listener = object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(view: View?) {
            val b = this@MainActivity.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
            println("${b?.text}")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Apply this plugin

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

And after set click listener to view like this

```
toggleButton1?.setOnCheckedChangeListener{ _, isCheked ->
    textView1?.text = if (isChecked) "ON" else "OFF"
}
```

**Update**

There is no problem to do same without kotlin synthetics

```
val toggleButton1: ToggleButton? = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1)
val textView1: TextView? = findViewById(R.id.textView1)
toggleButton1?.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->  } {
    textView1?.text = if (isChecked) "ON" else "OFF"
}
```

Comment: Kotlinx synthetic is deprecated. https://proandroiddev.com/migrating-the-deprecated-kotlin-android-extensions-compiler-plugin-to-viewbinding-d234c691dec7